# Как убрать переход на дефолтную страницу из другого проекта в Django 2

Tags: python, django, pycharm, редирект

Создал проект в PyCharm, через консоль среды создал django проект и для удобства указал дефолтную страницу, что бы при нажатии на ссылку, открывалась именно конкретная страница - http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/list.

После, создал ещё один django проект (пустой). Запускаю сервер, открываю страницу и наблюдаю, что в url, к http://127.0.0.1:8000, дописывается путь к шаблону из первого проекта. Т.е. вместо http://127.0.0.1:8000 идёт редирект на http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/list.

Пробовал пересоздать проект, но всё равно, при запуске, происходит перенаправление. Далее попробовал в первом проекте убрать функию, перенаправляющую на дефолтную страницу, но после сохранения, всё равно происходит редирект, как в первом проекте, так и во втором.

Подскажите, в чём может быть причина такого поведения? Смотрел файл settings.py, ничего такого не нашёл.

Comment: Какой тип редиректа Вы использовали? Браузер мог запомнить его и сразу обращаться по последнему адресу. Попробуйте очистить кэш.

Comment: Спасибо! Попробовал другой браузер. Открылась стартовая страница. Странно, что до очистки кэша, при удалении из url /blog/list, он всё равно дописывался.

Comment: ну тут явно было дело не в джанго. проекты джавно друг от друга не зависят. проблему надо было искать в IDE, в своей невнимательноси (забыли отключить первый проект) ну или в иных источниках проблем

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Современные браузере кэшируют редиректы.
Такое поведение используется, чтобы экономить время и трафик пользователя.

Обычно это происходит, если использовать следующие коды:

- `301 Moved Permanently`
- `308 Permanent Redirect`

Из описания ясно, что данные редиректы постоянны и навряд ли изменятся.

---

В Вашем случае для решения проблемы следует просто очистить кэш браузера.

Comment: CTRL + F5 надо бы нажать...

Comment: И зачем использовать слово "редирект", когда есть русское "перенаправление"? (придираюсь, сорри)

Comment: Зачем использовать английское слово сорри,
когда есть русское "извините"?

Comment: `Ctrl` + `F5` - это частный случай очистки кэша. Насчёт англицизмов - пожалуйста, давайте не будем разводить холивар. Если сообщение можно улучшить, то стоит предложить правку. Я специально оставлю решение по её принятию на других проверяющих.